# Visual Studio For Mac

Tags: macos, development, ide

If I want to use VS to use Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android do I have to keep Xamarin Studio installed on my Mac? VS has always been my favorite IDE, I don't really like Xamarin Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [System Requirements for Visual Studio for Mac](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-mac):

> - NET Core SDK 1.1 is required to use .NET Core projects and features. It can be downloaded and installed separately, and requires Mac OS X
>     El Capitan 10.11 or higher.
> - Xamarin.Android requires the 64-bit Java Development Kit (JDK).
> - Xamarin.iOS requires Apple's Xcode IDE and iOS SDK.
> - Xamarin.Forms can target both Android and iOS platforms, given the requirements listed above.

It makes no mention of Xamarin Studio being required.